# Forfiles with log

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I'm trying to use bat file as a command for deleting files older than 10 days in a folder. The code is like this:

```
forfiles -p "E:\folder" -m *.* /D -10 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

However, I'm not able to figure out how to get a log file populated everytime it's run. 
I've tried this below, that works with robocopy, however doesn't work with forfiles.

```
forfiles -p "E:\folder" -m *.* /D -10 /C "cmd /c del @path" /LOG+:E:\folder\log.txt
```

Would you know how shall I write this code so I have a log file populated with information of deletion?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why you would attempt to use the /LOG option.  It is not an option for the `DEL` command.

Comment: well yeah, I realized that, however, I'm not sure how to get such log in DEL command like I do using robocopy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/LOG` belongs to robocopy an thus it's not working.

In your example you're also trying to write the logfile into the same folder you are deleting the files from. Perhaps that is wanted, but i'm just saying...

Like following it should work (will only log files which can't be deleted):

```
forfiles -p "E:\folder" -m *.* /D -10 /C "cmd /c del @path >> E:\anotherfolder\log.txt"
```

---

The following will log all files which are processed through forfiles.
(but will not show if deletion was successful or not)

```
forfiles -p "E:\folder" -m *.* /D -10 /C "cmd /c del @path&echo @path >> E:\anotherfolder\log.txt"
```

Comment: You're right, this works fine, thank you. However, one little issue appeared, the log file is empty :-D Would you know by a chance why is that? Thanks

Comment: @Turpan The `>` is redirecting the output of the `del`-command to the file. Means, if the file is empty there were no files to delete.

Comment: Well, I have actually tested it with files that were really deleted, it has only created the empty file. Couldn't it be that it permanently deletes the files and thus, nothing to write in the log file?

Comment: @Turpan My mistake...the opposite is the case. Only files which could not be deleted are written into the log. Also you need to use `>>` to append the output to the file, otherwise the file is overwritten everytime. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Well, that would be also fine, however, the txt file is still empty.

Comment: @Turpan The file will be empty unless one or more files cannot be deleted (locked or no permission or ...).

Comment: I see, that's possible since I'm deleting only files older than 10 days. Isn't there a code that would always append the txt file with the list of files that were deleted at that time?